# Deshabilitar cambio de tamaño de button en bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo un botón con los estilos de bootstrap 4 que cuando la pantalla se hace más pequeña se hace la fuente de texto y el botón también más pequeño. Pero deseo que ese botón no cambie de tamaño. He probado fijando el estilo de la fuente con `font:16px !important` pero no funciona. ¿Hay alguna manera de deshabilitar este comportamiento en ese botón?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" style="letter-spacing: 0; font: 16px !important; border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0 0 3px 0; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; background-color: #2E2E2E !important; border-color: #2E2E2E !important; color: #149DCC !important;"
  class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

    Opciones
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba usando "font-size" en vez de "font".

Comment: Se me paso que era font-size !! Gracias !

Comment: @CuadCode, cuando trates de responder alguna publicación, recuerda dar una respuesta completa. En este caso indicas el uso de font-size, a eso agrégale el como usarlo y un ejemplo mínimo del resultado.

Comment: De acuerdo :D @Excorpion